# Triggers does cannot be created in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

following is a trigger which I created in MySQL Workbench and the related tables are below as well. the trigger works perfectly in workbench but when I try to created the same trigger in phpMyAdmin, it gives me the follow error

**Error**

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

> ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
>       STR: //
>       SQL: delimiter //
>       CREATE TRIGGER log_user_delete
>       BEFORE DELETE ON user
>       FOR EACH ROW
>       BEGIN
>       INSERT INTO log_user(user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_no, user_type, email, password, active, modified_by, modified_on,
>   modified_from) SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_no,
>   user_type, email, password, active, modified_by, modified_on,
>   modified_from FROM user WHERE OLD.user_id = user_id;

**SQL query: Documentation**

```
delimiter // CREATE TRIGGER log_user_delete BEFORE DELETE ON user FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO log_user(user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_no, user_type, email, password, active, modified_by, modified_on, modified_from) SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_no, user_type, email, password, active, modified_by, modified_on, modified_from FROM user WHERE OLD.user_id = user_id;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER log_user_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON user
FOR EACH ROW' at line 1.
```

what am I doing wrong?

2 tables :-

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    contact_no VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    user_type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    active INT(1) NOT NULL,
    modified_by INT(11) NOT NULL,
    modified_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified_from VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE log_user (
    log_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    contact_no VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    user_type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    active INT(1) NOT NULL,
    modified_by INT(11) NOT NULL,
    modified_on DATETIME,
    modified_from VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    log_modified_by INT(11) NOT NULL,
    log_modified_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    log_modified_from VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (log_id)
);
```

Trigger :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER log_user_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON user
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO log_user(user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_no, user_type, email, password, active, modified_by, modified_on, modified_from) SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_no, user_type, email, password, active, modified_by, modified_on, modified_from FROM user WHERE OLD.user_id = user_id;
UPDATE log_user SET status = 'DELETED' WHERE log_id = last_insert_id();
END;
// DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please, [read this link on SQL comments](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements006.htm). AFAIK, there is no `//`, only `/* stuffs */`